# How to execute a .sh file when the session starts?

Tags: bash

I have a .sh file that I execute just going to the containing folder and writing ./file.sh.

I want to execute that file when the session starts, so i create a symlink in /etc/init.d.

I expected it was executed when I start the session but it doesn't work..

The file has the "x" written next to the permissions, so I think it is executable.

Any help?

Javi

Comment: Uhmm.. What do you mean by session? Opening terminal or gnome session?

Comment: I mean after logging in Ubuntu.

Comment: In this case follow *tiempjuuh* answer.

Answer (score 7):

Dash-->Startup Applications-->Add-->*/path/to/your/.sh*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`/etc/init.d/` contains scripts that are being executed when *system* starts.
If you want to start `file.sh` every time you open a terminal, place a call to this script in your `.bashrc` file:

```
# Start this awesome script
. /path/file.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

There are easily a billion ways to do this but starting where you have, to add something to the old init system you need to run the following:

```
sudo update-rc.d foo defaults
```

Where `foo` is your script name.

Some popular alternatives:

- Edit `/etc/rc.local` to call your script before the `exit`.
- [Create an upstart script](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html). This is the replacement for System-V init that Ubuntu has carried for the past few releases. It's fairly good if you want more control over when your script is called but it's a more work.
- Launch it from within your X session (if this is a graphical machine) via gnome or another method (there are probably half a billion of these methods alone)

Answer (score 0):

In the startup applications list add command below

```
sh <path to your file>.sh
```

make sure the file is marked as executable. i recommend to keep the file in home folder.

Comment: If you put `sh` in front of the script (as in your example), it is not required to be executable.

Answer (score 0):

or

```
~/.config/autostart/ --->Create a file (filename.desktop)
filename.desktop in file add:
#!/bin/bash

[Desktop Entry]
Name=startdeskapp
GenericName=Program
Comment=auto start a sample 
#
Exec=startdesk.sh # app file name (default as bin/)
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=icon.png
Categories=Network;
StartupNotify=false
```