# .sh file on Startup Applications isn't executed

Tags: bash, scripts, startup-applications

## This is a followup to [a question about dialog boxes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510959/show-a-dialog-box-after-a-period-of-inactivity).

I want to show a dialog box both at the start of a session, and after *n* minutes of inactivity. I have decided to use `zenity` and `xautolock`. I have success invoking both from the command line (bash).

```
zenity --text=text --warning
xautolock -time 15 -locker "zenity --text=sometext --warning"
```

However, there are some constraints:

- The text has multiple words. If it has spaces, `zenity` will only show the first word and try to parse the other words as parameters. To fix this, I enclose the text in double quotes (`"`), but it leads to:
- `xautolock` takes the entire `zenity` command as an option for its `-locker` parameter. The command has multiple words, so I have to enclose it in quotes. But it already had quotes originally, so it conflicts on quotes-inside-quotes.
- I want the alert text to be customizable, so I'm using `--text="$(cat .filename)"`.

So now what I have is:

```
zenity --text="$(cat .filename)" --warning
xautolock -time 15 -locker "zenity --text=\"$(cat .filename)\" --warning"
```

If I run each line separately on a terminal session (bash), **they do work**. The cursor gets stalled waiting for the process to terminate, but the dialog boxes are displayed the way I need them.

Now I need it to start automatically with no user intervention. What I did:

- I've put each line separetedly on the [Startup Applications](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingProgramToSessionStartup) list. Instead of showing the desired text, they will show **$(cat** on the dialog box.
- I created a `command.sh` file on my `~` folder, pasted these two lines, made it executable.
- Running the script from the command line works.
- **Puting `~/command.sh` as an entry on Startup Applications does not work**. Nothing happens, nothing is displayed, no error message, nothing. According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87162/how-to-execute-a-sh-file-when-the-session-starts), it should work.
- Putting /home/username/command.sh does work, but this user is just [a "skel" that gets copied to a guest user](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession#Special_purpose_user) folder created upon login, so the username folder will be "guest-RANDOMSTRING", and I can't set is as a Startup Applications entry. For permission reasons, I can't set in to the "skel" user as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out each entry on the Startup Applications list gets created as a `.desktop` file on `~/.config/autostart$`.

As mentioned by both [@muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/511919/110157) and [an answer on the question he linked](https://askubuntu.com/a/251772/110157), `.desktop` files don't expand the tilde as the shell would. Neither they seem to have the ${HOME} variable.

So the solution was to add the following line to [the `~/.pam_environment` file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2BAH4ALw.pam_environment):

```
PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:${HOME}/scripts
```

Then place my `.sh` script on the `~/scripts` folder, and add `script.sh`, no prefixes, to the Startup Applications list.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting them in a script and adding that script as the entry in your Startup Applications. It's hard enough to use environment variables and `~` in desktop files, let alone full-fledged command substitution, as evinced by [Desktop Files don't seem to use $PATH correctly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248504/desktop-files-dont-use-seem-to-use-path-correctly) and [How to include environment Variable in launcher for icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476233/how-to-include-environment-variable-in-launcher-for-icon).

Comment: Thanks, your comment and the first link have led me in the right direction!